# HTML - Dart How to display rich text document such as RTF

Tags: html, css, dart

I need to display formatted help information in a scroll-able element in my first web page but have not been able to find examples using Google.  How is this best done?

Comment: I would think HTML fits for formatted help information and can be displayed in a scrollable area. Can you explain with a little more detail what you try to accomplish and what requirements you have.

Comment: @gunter My web page must fit entirely on a display the size that an iPad 2 has.  I have a look and feel, more or less, and have a '?' on the page that is clickable for help. I want the help to scroll and want to be able to style words with bold etc.   After I posted I discovered and am experimenting with an iFrame and an html file using <details>, <summary>, etc. My other thought was to display an RTF file in a scrollable area. This is all new to me ...

Comment: I suggest to go with HTML. There are ways to create HTML from RTF if you really need but HTML should offer all you need for formatted text.

Comment: You have confirmed my gut feeling, Gunter, Google failed me here - or I didn't have the right search words.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an acceptable answer for me is to use `<iframe>` with `<details>`, `<summary>`, and whatever HTTP5 has available for formatting text.